# Why my function is being executed only once?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm trying to make a program which finds out the longest strand of certain type of subsequence in the DNA, and then write it down into corresponing `sub_sequences` dictionary value.
The problem is that even though the loop executes 8 times (as much as i need), the function works only on the first execution. What's wrong here?

```python
import sys
import csv

def main():

    # Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        exit()

    # Read database file into a variable
    database = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

    # Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    DNA_sequence = open(sys.argv[2], "r")

    # Makes a dictionary of kinds of sequences
    sub_sequences = {0: ["AGATC", 0], 1: ["TTTTTTCT", 0], 2: ["AATG", 0], 3: ["TCTAG", 0], 4: ["GATA", 0], 5: ["TATC", 0], 6: ["GAAA", 0], 7: ["TCTG", 0]}

    # Finds the longest match of each STR in DNA sequence

    sub_sequences_length = len(sub_sequences)

    for i in range(sub_sequences_length):
        sub_sequences[i][1] = longest_match(DNA_sequence.read(), sub_sequences[i][0])

    return


def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)

    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return longest run found
    return longest_run


main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You call `DNA_sequence.read()` multiple times.

The documentation for [`TextIOBase::read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read) says:

> Read and return at most size characters from the stream as a single str. If size is negative or None, reads until EOF.

In other words, the first time you read the file, it reads the entire file, attemting to call `read` again, will result in reading nothing and you get an empty string back.

---

A simple fix is to store the contents of the file in a variable, and reuse that variable:

```py
# Read DNA sequence file into a variable
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as dna:
  DNA_sequence = dna.read()
```

Now you can use `DNA_sequence` variable which contains the contents of the file:

```py
longest_match(DNA_sequence, sub_sequences[i][0])
```